# Texmaker open file interface garbled

Tags: fonts, qt, latex, fontconfig

I have a problem when using Texmaker. When I use Texmaker to open a file, its user interfaces garbled.
My OS is archlinux. I have tried system update and software reinstallation. It doesn't help.
I asked this question in tex stack exchange forum, they told me that Texmaker uses Qt. Is it related to Qt?
[image]

If I launch Texmaker from console, it shows the following warning message on console:

```
<pre>(texmaker:84842): Pango-<font color="#C4A000"><b>WARNING</b></font> **: <font color="#3465A4">00:26:03.647</font>: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is &apos;DejaVu Sans Semi-Condensed 11&apos;
  
(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.647: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'DejaVu Sans Semi-Condensed 11'

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.647: font_face status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.647: scaled_font status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.650: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'DejaVu Sans Semi-Condensed 11'

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.650: font_face status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.650: scaled_font status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.699: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'DejaVu Sans Bold Semi-Condensed 11'

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.699: font_face status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.699: scaled_font status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.701: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'DejaVu Sans Bold Semi-Condensed 11'

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.701: font_face status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.701: scaled_font status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.707: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'DejaVu Sans Bold Semi-Condensed 15.83984375'

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.707: font_face status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.707: scaled_font status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.710: failed to create cairo scaled font, expect ugly output. the offending font is 'DejaVu Sans Bold Semi-Condensed 15.83984375'  

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.710: font_face status is: file not found

(texmaker:84842): Pango-WARNING **: 00:26:03.710: scaled_font status is: file not found
```

Comment: Do you have the `DejaVu Sans` font installed?   or did something corrupt the font, perhaps?   I don't use Arch myself, but according to the [arch wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Fonts), the Deja Vu fonts are in the `ttf-dejavu` package.

Comment: The rectangular blocks are indicative of GUI font problem. It may be missing, corrupt, or trying to display code points which are not defined in the font file. The error messages  make it clear which: "file not found". So start troubleshooting/researching from there.